# Which price Google accepts for the Magento Grouped Products?

Tags: product, magento-1, google-product-feeds

I want to create the product feed to submit to Google.
I want to know how does Google accept the price for the Grouped products?

Will it be sum of the price of all the associated simple products?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure google does. We have created our own feed that lists the individual simples. If any of the simples are not visible individually we submit the simples product details with the grouped product url. Not sure if this is best practise but this seem to be working for us.